# Using Mac-style (Option+u) umlaut compositon with IBUS

Tags: 14.04, ibus

I am using the IBUS input method to alternate between US-English (my actual keyboard layout) and googlepinyin. However, occasionally I need to write German umlauts as well (ß,ä, ü, ö). There is the compose-key sequence that I just used to type the sample umlauts, which works, but I find it rather inconvenient. Is there a way to configure for Apple-stype umlaut generation (on my mac: OPTION+u, release, then the character you want as umlaut, e.g. OPTION+u, release, a --> ä)? I find this more convenient. Of course I could just add a German keyboard layout to switch to, but that I would also find rather inconvenient.

I gooled extensively, and I found some pointers on how to make this work in general, but none those methods seem to work with ibus.

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, all you need is to edit the keyboard layout and add a dead key for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. Let’s start:

Well, if you use US keyboard layout you need two additional things: **right-alt** and the **dead key**.

Let's do this in steps:

**1. Backup the current layout:**

First of all, make a backup from the US layout, so open a terminal and type:

`cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`

`sudo cp us us.bkp`

**2. Open the layout file for editing:**

Enter in the same terminal:

`sudo gedit us`

You can see lines like this:

```
default
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys 
xkb_symbols "basic" {

name[Group1]= "USA";

// Alphanumeric section
key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
…
```

Now you can make changes in the **basic** block which begins on the 3rd line here.

**3. Enable right-alt or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>:**

Add the line `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` which makes something like this:

```
    xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"

    name[Group1]= "USA";
```

**4. Add the dead-key:**

Find the following line:

```
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
```

and change it to something like this:

```
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U,     dead_diaeresis       ]   };

(be careful about the *comma* after the capital U).
```

Now your layout is ready.

**5. Save and close** the file.

**6. Make changes take effect:**

Return to the terminal and run the following command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`

**7. Log out!**

Or if you have more than one layouts, just change the layout once.

---

### Alternatively

you may want to insert additional characters just with a single right-alt hit, i.e. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for Ü, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Ä, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for Ö, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for ß. In this case, instead of adding the dead-key (**step 4**) you should:

**4. Add characters to the 3rd level:**

Add all characters one by one, like this:

```
key <AD07> {    [     u,    U,     udiaeresis,     Udiaeresis       ]   };
key <AD08> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
key <AD09> {    [     o,    O,     odiaeresis,     Odiaeresis       ]   };
…
key <AC01> {    [     a,    A,     adiaeresis,     Adiaeresis       ]   };
key <AC02> {    [     s,    S,     ssharp       ]   };
```

Again, be careful about commas and the capitals – they are necessary.

All the rest is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have tried both, but it seems that ibus simply overrides the xkb settings. Without ibus, I can't switch to Chinese input, so I need to keep it active. The English keyboard layouts offered by ibus also aren't the same as the ones listed in the kxb/symbols files. I guess I will have to keep trying...

Comment: Okay, after also running `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, it now works as expected, on the command line as well as in XFCE/ibus. Thanks again, very much!

Comment: The command is essential. I edited the answer to make it clearer. You’re welcome! I’m happy for it was useful.

Comment: Works well! If you want to immediately activate it, use `setxkbmap us MY_VARIANT` where `MY_VARIANT` corresponds to `xkb_symbols "MY_VARIANT"`!

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04, you can achieve this simply by switching to the "English (Macintosh)" layout in the settings panel:

[image: Settings]
[image]

Comment: Do I understand this correctly to enable the option key (mod4/super) to behave as it does under macOS for English keyboards? How to do this is something I've been beating my head against X/Linux keyboard configuration every few months for years now. ;)

Comment: `English (Macintosh)` is not available on 18.04